# How to find Mongoose document by querying the sub document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**In short**

I need to select all the dashboard entries with the current `user` having the role `admin` in my mongo - mangoose

---

**In detail**

My Schema looks like this

```
var DashboardSchema = new Schema({
    members: [new Schema({
        user: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: 'User cannot be empty'
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            required: 'User role cannot be empty',
            enum: ['admin', 'member'],
            default: 'member'
        }
    })]
});
```

My database collection looks like this.

```
{   "_id" : ObjectId("5688fa7991d9574c13198060"),
    "members" : [ 
        { "user" : ObjectId("5688fa7991d9574c1319805f"), "role" : "admin" }, 
        { "user" : ObjectId("5688fa6591d9574c1319805c"), "role" : "member" }  
    ]}

{   "_id" : ObjectId("5688fabea58caa0021c7d936"),
    "members" : [ 
        { "user" : ObjectId("5688fa7991d9574c1319805f"), "role" : "admin"}
    ]}

{   "_id" : ObjectId("5688fa6591d9574c1319805d"),
    "members" : [ 
        { "user" : ObjectId("5688fa6591d9574c1319805c"), "role" : "admin"}, 
        { "user" : ObjectId("5688fa7991d9574c1319805f"), "role" : "member"}
    ]}
```

**Attempt 1**

I wrote this code, but it's giving errors

```
Dashboard.find({
    'members': {$in: {role: 'admin', user: req.user}}      
})
```

> { "message": "Something went wrong" }

**Attempt 2**

This code results the values but it's giving all the dashboard emtries with a at least one member.role is admin and one member.user is current user

```
Dashboard.find({
    'members.role': {$in: 'admin'},
    'members.user': {$in: req.user},
})
```

> results all three documents

I need to select all the dashboard entries with the current `user` having the role `admin`. That is when the query executes it should return the first two documents.

- 5688fabea58caa0021c7d936
- 5688fa7991d9574c13198060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
Dashboard.find(
   { members: { $elemMatch: { user: req.user, role: 'admin' } } }
)
```

Comment: Thank you. you are a life saver :)